# Update namespace names in all class files after moving classes to folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, directory

In Visual Studio 2015, if I reorganize and add classes to new folders, how do I blanket update for all my class' namespaces?

For example, if I have a few classes in namespace "Project", and I move the class files into a folder named "Tests", Visual studio wants to change the namespace for all the classes from "Project" to "Project.Tests".

Is there a way to update all my class files at the same time with the new namespace name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Find and Replace feature.

Comment: True that would work with the addition of just one folder, but I added 4 new folders to the project.  So there are different namespace names for several different classes.  I suppose I could do a Find/Replace for each folder though.